# Another definition for 'to go on a diet'

Tags: expression-choice

What other words or expression could be used to say *to go/ be on a diet*,  meaning to follow healthy nutrition rules mainly to lose weight.

Comment: One short expression: [_eat right_](http://www.everydaychoices.org/eat.html).

Comment: "watching one's weight"

Comment: @Jack To go WAPF. :-)

Answer (score 2):

We talk about *caloric restriction* or when referring to decreased intake for the purpose of losing weight. There's no medical term for *good nutrition* per se that I'm aware of (though a nutritionist may well have a term for it).

I'd say, *nutritionally sound caloric restriction* may meet your need.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's **banting**, meaning "slimming by avoiding eating sugar, starch, and fat", as in this line from Agatha Christie's *The Thirteen Problems*, featuring my favorite detective, Miss Marple:

> "I must explain," broke off Sir Henry, "that Miss Clark, alarmed at her increasing stoutness, was doing a course of what is popularly known as *banting*."

(http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Banting, source listed as Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged)

I like it, and it's the most directly appropriate I can think of for your question, but undoubtedly that's an old-fashioned word, and probably too British.

**Watching your weight** and **eating healthy** seem to be your best bets for common phrases.

Comment: What is the definition of banting? Do you have a source besides a sentence in a novel?

Comment: Banting (diet) is a very specific weight loss program, like the Dukan or the Atkins diet, but it's still a great word. _We banted for weeks, didn't lose a single pound but, my god, we farted like trojans._

Comment: Apparently it means a specific _type_ of diet, which I guess could be also referred to as a "program": to lose weight by avoiding sugar, starch, and fat. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Banting http://www.second-opinions.co.uk/banting.html#.U16wkPldWSo Named after William Banting, who popularized the diet in 1863. I'm seeing it both stylized as "Banting" (which seems like a program) and "banting" (which just seems like a general word for diet), so this may be a miss in the end.

Comment: @medica Bantings original text can be found at http://www.lowcarb.ca/corpulence/corpulence_1.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider "[**lick oneself {back) into**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lick+into+shape) (shape, a healthier lifestyle, healthy eating habits, a "normal" weight, etc.)," and "[**shape oneself (back) up**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shape+up)."